# WPF Editable DataGrid backed by dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, datagrid

I have a DataGrid backed by an Observable collection of Dictionary. I'd like to perform edits via the grid and currently the UI doesn't seem to allow it. I also observe that when adding the IEditableObject interface to the Dictionary, the interface methods are called when a cell is clicked, but nothing happens on the UI itself.

Here's my minimum example:

```
    class MainWindowViewModel
    {
        public MainWindowViewModel() {
            ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<DataGridData> {
                new DataGridData() {{"Name", "Abe"},{"Age", "50"},{"Gender", "Male"}},
                new DataGridData() {{"Name", "Shelly"},{"Age", "20"},{"Gender", "Female"}
                }
            };
        }

        public ObservableCollection<DataGridData> ItemsSource { get; set; }
    }

    public class DataGridData : Dictionary<string, string>, IEditableObject {
        public void BeginEdit(){}

        public void CancelEdit(){}

        public void EndEdit(){}
    }

    public partial class MainWindow {
        public MainWindow() {
            DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();

            InitializeComponent();
            foreach (var col in ViewModel.ItemsSource[0].Keys) {
                AddColumns(col, col);
            }

        }

        MainWindowViewModel ViewModel {
            get { return DataContext as MainWindowViewModel; }
        }

        void AddColumns(string id, string name)
        {
            FrameworkElementFactory textBlock = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));

            textBlock.SetValue(TextBlock.PaddingProperty, new Thickness(2));
            textBlock.SetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding(string.Format("[{0}]", id)));

            Binding textDecorationBinding = new Binding();
            textDecorationBinding.ElementName = "DataGrid";
            textDecorationBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("DataContext.TextDecoration");

            textBlock.SetValue(TextBlock.TextDecorationsProperty, textDecorationBinding);

            DataTemplate cellTemplate = new DataTemplate();
            cellTemplate.VisualTree = textBlock;

            DataGridTemplateColumn column = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
            column.Header = name;
            column.SortMemberPath = name;
            column.CellTemplate = cellTemplate;

            DataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
        }
    }

<Window x:Class="Datagrid.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid 
            Name="DataGrid"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource}"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            >
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The dictionary is used because I don't anything about the column data at compile time. The ItemsSource above is just an example but I could have any number of key/values at run time.

What changes are necessary to enable editing the cell data?

**Edit**
I've never used it, but I'm reading about using reflection to emit an actual class that could replace the dictionary key/values. I may give this a go unless someone has contrary advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opition your code is a little bit "tortuous". Indeed I wouldn't use a Dictionary as model of the objects which I want to handle. In my opinion it is better to use a specialized class (in this way you can implement the "famous" `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface).
For example you can use a Person class (here a very fast implementation of it):

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public Genders Gender { get; set; }
}
```

You can implement `IEditableObject`, but it is not mandatory.

Last (but not the least) if I were you, I will declare DataGrid columns in my XAML and not in my code (I can't see a valid reason for using code in your situation; I don't know maybe you need to have dynamic columns. In this case you can read this very good [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/676530/How-to-Add-Columns-to-a-DataGri)).

So my ViewModel is (you can easy replace `Dictionary` with `Person` class):

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        People = new ObservableCollection<Dictionary<string, string>> {
            new Dictionary<string, string>() {{"Name", "Abe"}, {"Age", "50"}, {"Gender", "Male"}},
            new Dictionary<string, string>() {{"Name", "Shelly"}, {"Age", "20"}, {"Gender", "Female"}}
        };
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Dictionary<string, string>> People { get; private set; } 
}
```

My XAML (if you replaced Dictionary with Person, remove the square brackets from the columns bidings):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=People}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=[Name]}" Header="Name" Width="2*" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=[Age]}" Header="Age" Width="*" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=[Gender]}" Header="Gender" Width="*" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

My window code-behind:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

In this way, everything works fine and you can edit data by using the `DataGrid`.
I hope this sample can help you.

**EDIT**

If you need to use your approach, probably in your `AddColumns` method you are missing to declare a `CellEditingTemplate`. Your method will become:

```
private void AddColumns(string id, string name)
{
    FrameworkElementFactory textBlock = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));

    textBlock.SetValue(TextBlock.PaddingProperty, new Thickness(2));
    textBlock.SetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding(String.Format("[{0}]", id)));

    FrameworkElementFactory textBox = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBox));

    textBox.SetValue(TextBox.PaddingProperty, new Thickness(2));
    textBox.SetValue(TextBox.TextProperty, new Binding(String.Format("[{0}]", id)));

    Binding textDecorationBinding = new Binding();
    textDecorationBinding.ElementName = "DataGrid";
    textDecorationBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("DataContext.TextDecoration");

    textBlock.SetValue(TextBlock.TextDecorationsProperty, textDecorationBinding);

    DataTemplate cellTemplate = new DataTemplate();
    cellTemplate.VisualTree = textBlock;

    DataTemplate cellEditingTemplate = new DataTemplate();
    cellEditingTemplate.VisualTree = textBox;

    DataGridTemplateColumn column = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
    column.Header = name;
    column.SortMemberPath = name;
    column.CellTemplate = cellTemplate;
    column.CellEditingTemplate = cellEditingTemplate;

    DataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
}
```

I read that you are thinking to use reflection to emit an actual class that could replace the dictionary key/values. Of course this is a solution, but I suggest to consider [ICustomTypeDescriptor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.componentmodel.icustomtypedescriptor(v=vs.110).aspx) or [CustomTypeDescriptor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.componentmodel.customtypedescriptor(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I'd go this route if I could, but actual run time values can be any set of key/value pairs. I edited above.